# React + TypeScript: 'React' refers to a UMD global but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead. (Justification)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

We are using React and TypeScript in our current project and I come across below behavior.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

I replace the above line with the one below since it seems to be using `Component` import only.

```
import { Component } from 'react';
```

And I was thrown below error

> Error: 'React' refers to a UMD global but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.

I tried looking it up on Stack and GitHub, found few articles and discussion but still unclear about why it's happening.

Would be more interested in whether React or Typescript is throwing it and WHY ? Not the ways to fix it.

Also some light around UMD, why it's used here ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64656055/react-refers-to-a-umd-global-but-the-current-file-is-a-module)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way [JSX syntax is transpiled](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html) depends on [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), `jsxFactory` option defaults to `React.createComponent`. This means that `<p/>` is transpiled to `React.createComponent('p')`, and `React` is expected to exist in the scope of a module.

If there's no `React` import, it's expected that `React` global should exist.

Comment: that means if I'm not using `tsx` inside my `render` method, it will run fine ? Also, if IMO react creates a full virtual dom object before transpiling JSX to actual DOM, that means one react import at super parent level should be fine ? 
Could you also attach some links for reference which can be helpful in understanding this transpiling process better.

Comment: I linked to the manual. It's not related to virtual DOM or how React works. If you use JSX syntax in a module, you can be sure that React.createElement will be used, so React is needed to be imported, If you don't use JSX, you may not need it to be imported. As a rule of thumb, it should be imported in .tsx files to avoid this error.

Comment: Thanks, I will go through the links and get back to you if needed. Would like to keep it unanswered for some time so that other's can also give their inputs.

Answer (score 19):

Are you rendering any jsx in the file? If so, you do need to import React, since those jsx tags compile into calls to `React.createElement()`. Without the import, the references to React are trying to reference a global variable, which then results in that error.

If you're using eslint, i'd recommend using eslint-plugin-react and turning on the rule [react-in-jsx-scope](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/react-in-jsx-scope.md), which will catch this case.

Comment: could you please answer my comment in other answer ?

Comment: If you're not using JSX, then you don't need to import React. Each file that uses JSX needs its own import of React. Transpiling JSX is done at build time, not runtime; the virtual DOM isn't created until runtime.

Comment: Since React 17 the `React` import is no longer required for JSX files.

Answer (score 1):

With the [introduction of a new JSX transform in React 17](https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html), it is no longer necessary to import `React` in every file that uses JSX. Simply edit the [`jsx` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#jsx) in your `tsconfig` to use `"react-jsx"`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "react-jsx"
    }
}
```

The old default transformation (`"jsx": "react"`), compiled JSX into calls to `React.createElement`, so `React` had to be in scope for it to work. The `react-jsx` transform, however, uses the `_jsx` function and automatically inserts the import for it.

After this change, unused imports of `React` can be safely removed. After upgrading to the newer JSX transform, you may run the following command in the root of your project to remove such useless imports.

```
npx react-codemod update-react-imports
```